# How to Constraint on TextBox in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I try constraint for `TextBox` in C#. I succesfull this for users can put *only numbers*:

```
private void TxtID_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsControl(e.KeyChar);          
    }
```

Now, I wonder how can users just write `11` char in `TextBox`? I try `char.Max` or `Min` but i can't in the `KeyPress` event.

Comment: Try `MaxLength` property; `TxtID.MaxLength = 11; // At most 11 characters`

Comment: *Paste* is yet another possibility to put text into `TextBox`. It seems you want to write some code in `TextChanged`

Comment: Maybe just using a NumericUpDown control would make things easier for you.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko i was try that but i take error about defination MaxLength. I can do it in propertys for transient.

Comment: @Callout: what actually went wrong? What's error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
  public MyForm() 
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    // At most 11 characters
    TxtID.MaxLength = 11;
  }

  private void TxtID_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
  {
    // char.IsDigit is too wide: it returns true on any unicode digit (e.g. Persian ones)
    e.Handled = (e.KeyChar < '0' || e.KeyChar > '9') && !char.IsControl(e.KeyChar);          
  }

  // On Paste we should validate the input:
  // what if user copy "bla-bla-bla 1234" and paste it to TxtID?
  private void TxtID_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) 
  {
    Control ctrl = (sender as Control);

    string value = string.Concat(ctrl
      .Text
      .Where(c => c >= '0' && c <= '9'));

    if (value != ctrl.Text)
      ctrl.Text = value;
  }
```